# Why this button is not showing in Linear Layout?

Tags: android, android-layout

I'm trying to add a button to the end of the screen, so I wrapped the content in LinearLayout, and added another LinearLayout for the button on the end. But it's now showing...

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".NasaDailyImage">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <ScrollView
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/imageTitle"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="@string/test_image_title" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/imageDate"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="@string/test_image_date" />

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/imageDisplay"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                    android:src="@drawable/test_image" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/imageDescription"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="@string/test_image_description" />

            </LinearLayout>
        </ScrollView>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center">

            <Button
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/refresh" />
        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Any idea what's wrong here?

Comment: because your scrollview is `fill_parent`, so it takes all the available space

Comment: fill_parent has been deprecated for ages, you should switch to match_parent.

Comment: not, i did try wrap_content for ScrollView layout_height, but it still doesn't show

Comment: wrap_content for scrollView doesn't work, it will always be fill_parent or some exact number in dps

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `ScrollView` fills the parent, so there is no more room for the `LinearLayout`.

Instead, specify the `LinearLayout` first, and position the `ScrollView` above it:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".NasaDailyImage">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:id="@+id/linearlayout"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center">

            <Button
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/refresh" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <ScrollView
            android:layout_above="@id/linearlayout"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent">

             ...
        </ScrollView>  

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: not, i did try wrap_content for ScrollView layout_height, but it still doesn't show

Comment: This solves the problem. But I really would like to understand why the button will not show as child of a LinearLayout with a ScrollView (even with hight=wrap_content).

Comment: It makes no sense to make the `ScrollView` `wrap_content`, since the content's height should be even larger than `match_parent`.

Answer (score 0):

Yes,

It's because you have fill_parent for height on your first LinearLayout

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"  ----> Makes it fill parent
    android:orientation="vertical">
```

Comment: the scroll and the button are childs of this LinearLayout, so what's wrong?

Answer (score 0):

you can try giving weights to scrollview and the button.
 if above doesn't solve make the parent layout as linearlayout and give weight sum to parent linearlayout as 1 and give child layouts layout weight i.e for scrollview 0.9 and button 0.1 with height of both child views 0dp.

Answer (score 0):

Another solution found is to add to scrollview:

```
android:layout_weight="1"
```

The `weight="1"` get the total remaining space.

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/linear.html#Weight